# want to rewrite url and want to remove page " detail.php?read=" from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Old URL

```
http://localhost/detail.php?read=hair-loss-reasons
```

New URL

```
http://localhost/hair-loss-reasons
```

This is dynamic URL

I want to change all dynamic urls dynamically in all url when we come on that page "detail.php?read=url " page and query string variable "read" should be removed and url directly come after website name or on local host it should come directly after `localhost/url` on local host as well as on server when some site is running

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for free work instead of help with a technical problem. Please reword your question to post an example of what you have tried so far that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this in your root directory of localhost.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ detail.php?read=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sir nothings happen , everything still remains the same

Comment: try the url like that http://localhost/hair-loss-reasons and it should rewrite to http://localhost/detail.php?read=hair-loss-reasons if detail.php is in proper place.